# How to find inductance using $\phi=L I$ for distributed current case?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

[image]

A current flows via two long coaxial cables.

Inductance is defined as
$\phi=L I$ but in this case where is the loop through which I should find the flux?

Is it even reasonable to define inductance using the above equation for these types of cases?

Thank you.